# Translating lat/lon coordinate on rotated/scaled maps

Tags: math, maps

I need to indicate a lat/lon coordinate in an old map like this:
http://www.davidrumsey.com/luna/servlet/detail/RUMSEY~8~1~3017~90020003:Topographical-Map-Of-The-City-and-C

Projected on Google Maps:
http://rumsey.geogarage.com/maps/g2784000.html

I know the bounding box of the map as well as the dimensions of the image in pixels, but I couldn't figure out how to locate a lat/lon within this map.

Upper left is (40.698291,-74.079051), Lower Left (40.659855,-73.979638), Lower Right (40.855232,-73.835582) and Upper Right (40.882919,-73.940263).

Is there a standard formula on how to do locate a lot/lon datum in the historic map?

Comment: Do you have the coordinates of the four corners?

Comment: I updated the question with a better example. Cool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you can assume your lat/lon coordinates to form a rectangular grid (which should be a reasonable approximation on a city scale, although it will fail for larger areas or very precise data), you can assume your transformation between coordinates to be a projective transformation. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) (or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14244616/1468366) if you prefer to stay on SO) for details on how to compute the corresponding transformation matrix and use that to convert coordinates.

Based on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/405559/35416) I did a bit of computation with [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/):

```py
def pm1(a, b, c, d):
    M = Matrix([a , b, c]).transpose()
    f = M.adjoint() * d
    return M*diagonal_matrix(f)
def pm(a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2):
    return pm1(a2, b2, c2, d2)*(pm1(a1, b1, c1, d1).adjoint())
P1 = vector(QQ, [0, 0, 1])
P2 = vector(QQ, [0, 1, 1])
P3 = vector(QQ, [1, 1, 1])
P4 = vector(QQ, [1, 0, 1])
Q1 = vector(QQ, [40698291, -74079051, 1000000]) # Upper left
Q2 = vector(QQ, [40659855, -73979638, 1000000]) # Lower left
Q3 = vector(QQ, [40855232, -73835582, 1000000]) # Lower right
Q4 = vector(QQ, [40882919, -73940263, 1000000]) # Upper right
M = pm(Q1, P1, Q2, P2, Q3, P3, Q4, P4)
M.change_ring(RDF)/1e40
```

The resulting formula reads like this:

```
z =   559.910562534*lat - 539.510073656*lon - 64123.7576703
x = (-5629.59680416*lat - 2176.56828347*lon + 67876.8560722)/z
y = ( 8466.61769096*lat - 11263.0392472*lon - 1178932.12938)/z
```

The resulting coordinates `x` and `y` are measuered from zero to one, where zero denotes the left resp. upper edge, and one the right resp. lower edge.

If the assumption of a rectangular grid is not enough, you'll need to know details about the projection used to create the map, so that you can relate map positions to spherical coordinates.