# How to transform image from 3d to 2d perspective

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to correct images so you look at it from the orthogonal plane. I have seen [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244032/redraw-image-from-3d-perspective-to-2d) question but do not know how to put the calculations into JavaScript code to perform the action.

So to upload an image, select four points on the image to become the new corners and then to crop.

For example, I want to select the four corners of the piece of paper in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWKsX.jpg) and then crop it to make it look as if I am looking at it directly.

Comment: Three clicks later following the first link i found http://jsfiddle.net/dFrHS/1/ ... ( -> mathSE -> proofOfConcept)

Comment: I have code that does that. It does not let me select the corners or auto rectify.